# Add image after link with certain class and href using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code...

```
<a href="test123.html" class="testclass">Test Link</a>
```

I need to add an image after the link but based on the class and href. I've attempted:

```
jQuery(".testclass a[href$='test123.html']").append("<br /><div style='padding:10px;'><img src='testimage.jpg'></div>");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `a.testclass[href$='test123.html']`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `after()` to insert after an element. `append()` is used to add a child element at the end of an element.

```
jQuery("a.testclass[href$='test123.html']").after("<br /><div style='padding:10px;'><img src='testimage.jpg'></div>");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rpXCF/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
jQuery("a.testclass[href$='test123.html']").after("<br /><div style='padding:10px;'><img src='testimage.jpg'></div>");
```

Should insert the div immediately after the selected elemtn.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is not correct. Should be

```
jQuery("a.testclass[href$='test123.html']").append(YourHtml)
```